# how do I put each seperate input onto a different txt file line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def write_csv_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as csv_file:
        file_name = csv_file
        write = input("please enter the number of times you would like to enter "
                      "a text into then file onto a different line: ")
        write = int(write)
        for write in range(write):
            x = input("please enter what you would like to add: ")
            file_name.write(x)

    exit()


xxx = input("please enter the name of the file you would like to print into: ")
print(write_csv_file(xxx))
```

Comment: Explicitly add the line break: `file_name.write(x + '\n')`

Answer (score 1):

Just add a line break to the write method;

```
file_name.write(f'{x}\n')
```

The `\n` part denotes a line break/new line.

Answer (score 1):

```
def write_csv_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as csv_file:
        file_name = csv_file
        write = input("please enter the number of times you would like to enter "
                      "a text into then file onto a different line: ")
        write = int(write)
        for write in range(write):
            x = input("please enter what you would like to add: ")
            file_name.write(x)
            file_name.write('\n')


    exit()


xxx = input("please enter the name of the file you would like to print into: ")
print(write_csv_file(xxx))
```

add `file_name.write('\n')` this after write text.

`\n` denotes new line or line break.